# Odoo 10 - Access denied for biller to register payment

Tags: nginx, permission-denied, odoo-10

I've two server environments, One for testing and the other for production.
Both are working on Ubuntu server 16 and running Odoo 10 Enterprise edition. The only difference is that on the production server I used Nginx to allow Odoo working on port 80 instead of 8069.

Before we migrate our database to the production server, everything was working smoothly. Now the problem is when the sales person who has permissions of "Sales / User: All Documents" and "Accounting & Finance / Billing" tries to register payments for an invoice he gets this message

[image]

However he doesn't get the same message in the test server in which the database is the same as the production server db. I checked the access control list of model "account.journal" in both databases and there was no difference between them. I checked the log file and found this error.

```
odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_model: Access Denied by ACLs for operation: write, uid: 38, model: account.journal
```

I understand the problem lies in the access permissions. But my question here is why the Sales person was able to register the payment in the test server but not in production server. can anyone help me to understand why this could happen and how to fix it. Could it be due to Nginx?!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can check your odoo version release, if you download odoo using git you can check it using **git log** command in your odoo directory, if your last commit is deferent ( local and productio ) maybe that is the problem.

Actually, you can update manually the access right for `account.journal` table.